# How to speed up/optimize singificantly a for-loop?

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing, iteration

How can I significantly speed up a `for` loop?

Example:

## Getting the data

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("AAPL", start="1978-01-01", end="2021-03-13")
data['smav'] = data.Close.rolling(window=21).mean()
data['lmav'] = data.Close.rolling(window=55).mean()
data = data.dropna()
data = data.reset_index(drop=False)
```

## Run a `For` Loop

```
start = time.time()
def signals(data):
    orders = []
    for i in range(1,len(data)-1):
        if data.smav[i-1] < data.lmav[i-1] and data.smav[i] > data.lmav[i]:
            orders.append({'time':data.Date[i], 'signal': 1, 'price': round(data.Open[i],3)})
        if data.smav[i-1] > data.lmav[i-1] and data.smav[i] < data.lmav[i]:
            orders.append({'time':data.Date[i], 'signal': -1, 'price': round(data.Close[i],3)})
    return orders

signals(data)
print(f'Time: {time.time() - start}')
```

P.S. I also tried to use `Pool` from `multiprocessing` but the difference in execution time wasn't significant.

Comment: Sorry Martin I'm new in stackoverflow. I tried to find a solution with similar arguments but I wasn't able to apply what I found, that's why I published a new post. I'm sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: It might be possible to improve your `multiprocessing` attempt (or suggest the use something else more suitable), but that's unlikely to happen without letting us see what you tried.

Comment: I think I understand. A common problem with multiprocessing is that each process runs in its own memory space, which means there's no shared global data among them. You can sometimes get around that by passing (and/or) returning the data, but then the overhead of doing _that_ cancels some or all of the speed advantage. There are some more advanced ways of sharing certain kinds of data, like dictionaries, that can reduce the overhead somewhat — but might not be applicable to data `yfinance` gives you. Sometimes multithreading can be used instead, but generally not for compute-bound processing.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I mean: if I run the above for loop, the execution time is around 0.64 seconds that is not bad for a single dataframe which contains around 10.000 entries but: what if I apply the def -signals- over, for example, 30 dataframes? The execution time will explode. With parallel programming, as you can see, I'm  a beginner and I would like to study some package but online there is a lot staff that make me confused. I treasure any advice you will give me.

Comment: I just remembered there a relatively new called [multiprocessing. shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html?highlight=shared_memory#module-multiprocessing.shared_memory) that you might be able to use to share data between the processes (input and/or output).

Comment: Basically I used yfinance just for giving you the possibility to run the code but I don't use it. Please can you tell me how i can use dictionaries? I do not want to disturb you, but if can give me a little input will be a good starting point. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Really thank you Mr. Martin. I appeciated your help.

Comment: Glad to help. To share a dictionary, you can use a `multiprocessing.Manager`. See the **Server process** subsection of [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) for an example.